# First link to internal page works. Subsequent attempt causes Http 404 Error in ASP.net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, http, http-status-code-404

I am using ASP.net 2.0 in VS 2008 with Framework 3.5, VB.net codebehind

I plan to build a website that would have a stationary menu on the left made with a TreeView in a fixed position div. A second div on the right would be for content. I have made a small test app to see if the concept works using Master / Content pages.

I want the menu to be hard coded in a single place. The Master page works well for that. The idea is to not have to edit the menu in separate pages as the site grows.

The test app has one Master page and one Contents page. That is how I would like to set up the actual website. The Contents page is the start up page. The Master page has the menu items. Each menu item links to Contents.aspx, but with a unique querystring or /keywords appended. The Contents page codebehind Load event reads the Request.Url.AbsoluteUri. Then, based on the appended querystring or /keywords, pulls the content data and pushes it to an empty Literal control on the Contents.aspx page. In this test app I just push plain text for simplicity.

This works well until I re-click a link. That causes an Http 404 error. I have tried using Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True at the top of the Master and Content Load events and that did not help. I can click one menu link several times and the page will keep reloading. But going back and forth between the links causes the error.

When the error occurs it happens before the Contents.aspx Load event starts.

I would like to be able to fix this in a way that will work on an asp.net host site.

MasterPage.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" 
Inherits="MasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div  style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:300px; height:100%; 
background-color:#ddd; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px" >
   <a href="Contents.aspx">Home</a><br />
    <a href="Contents.aspx?p=ABCD" >ABCD page</a><br />
    <a href="Contents.aspx/?p=WXYZ" >WXYZ page</a><br />
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:310px; width:40%; 
height:100%; background-color:#eee; padding-top:10px; padding-left:10px" >
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Contents.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Contents.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="Contents" MasterPageFile ="~/MasterPage.master" title="Contents"%>
<asp:Content ID="Contents" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
   <asp:Literal ID="Contents_Main" runat="server">
   </asp:Literal>
</asp:Content>
```

Contents.aspx.vb codebehind:

```
Partial Class Contents
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Sub Contents_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
Handles Me.Load
        Try
            Dim url As System.Uri = Request.Url
            Select Case True
                Case url.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("?p=ABCD")
                    Me.Contents_Main.Text = "content for ABCD"
                Case url.AbsoluteUri.EndsWith("?p=WXYZ")
                    Me.Contents_Main.Text = "content for WXYZ"
                Case Else
                    Me.Contents_Main.Text = "Landing Page"
            End Select
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.Contents_Main.Text = ex.Message & ex.StackTrace
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the same concept in a single aspx form, rather than Master/Content. The menu is now in that single form and the codebehind pulls the data for the content. I do not know what was causing the Http 404 error, but using the single aspx form resolved it. Also, the URL must include a querystring, in the form of www.example.com?s=values, not www.example.com/keyword1-keyword2. The latter syntax also threw the 404 error.